# Scroll To Refresh on Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, refresh, nsscrollview, pull-to-refresh

Is it possible to get the "pull-to-refresh" scrollview, present in many applications on iOS, on Lion? I have been able to get my view in the "bounce area" of the scroll view and detect when to refresh. My problem is keeping the view scrolled up while refreshing and then disabling that when it is done.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried so many things it is ridiculous. I have tried adding the "refresh view" to be a subview of the document and moving everything down its height and that works but it looks strange to see everything teleport downward. I'm looking for a natural looking solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally achieved this and I open-sourced my code here: https://github.com/alexzielenski/ScrollToRefresh